# 3V3 PSU Redesign. Noise issues

Tags: power-supply, decoupling-capacitor, 3.3v

Our initial design was using the TPS560430 chip as a step-down converted from a Vin of (12-16V) down to 3V3 with the 3V3 rail looking like this (Vpp is 120mV, sorry for the quality):
[image]

Because of the chip shortage, we were forced to replace the TPS chip with the NCV3063DR2G and the following design:

[image]

Unfortunately the 3V3 rail is looking much worse, badly affecting the readings of one of the sensors:
[image]

I can see in the PSU's chip datasheet that the recommended capacitor on the output is 470uF for 800mA of current. Our design barely goes above 20mA, so the thinking here was that the 150uF should be enough. Is there any way evading this problem? Here's what we've tried so far:

1. Replacing the 150uF electrolytic capacitor with 3x 47uF ceramic caps stacked onto each other as a test. The performance seems to have improved, although it's still worse than before.
   [image]
2. Have ordered 220uF ceramic capacitors for the output which should hopefully make things a bit better.

Is there any other more obvious solution? Neither of us is an expert in PSU design, so we might be missing something really obvious and simple here.

Thank you!

LE: PSU layout:
[image]

LE2: 3V3 plot with AC coupling selected
[image]

Comment: Show your board layout.

Comment: "The NCP3063 is a hysteretic, dc−dc converter that uses a gated oscillator"... I think you're just seeing the normal ripple for this type of circuit, but you'd need 5µs/div on the scope and AC mode to actually see what's happening...

Comment: Please show your probing setup. Is this a two layer design without ground plane?

Comment: @winny Yes, it's a 2 layer design. The previous one, with the TPS560 had an identical layer stack and it was much much better.

Comment: @bobflux: I've attached an updated scope plot on the original post. I've used AC coupling, but 200us / division. At 5us/div there was nothing to be shown.

Comment: Also, a friend suggested replacing L1 with 1 mH and R1 with a 1 Ohm resistor to reduce the voltage ripple.

Comment: Ouch! This would really benefit from a four layer PCB with ground plane.

Answer (score 4):

The scope shot at 200µs/div tells the story...

According to "operating description" on page 7 of [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp3063-d.pdf) , it's a hysteretic converter. It runs at a rather low frequency, with a small inductor... so the behavior is normal.

It's just a comparator that gates a clock and that controls the switch. So when output voltage is too low, it pumps a pulse into the inductor, and since the inductor value is quite low, that results in a substantial rise in output voltage. Then, the comparator notices output voltage is too high, and the chip does nothing until output voltage has dropped below the threshold again.

That explains the quick rise and slow fall on your output voltage.

If you want low ripple, basically don't use a hysteretic chip, use a PWM chip instead. For low ripple with a small inductor, it needs to run at high frequency, like TPS560430.

You could salvage this with a much higher inductor value and output capacitor value, but it's not guaranteed, and the high inductor value in a small package will probably saturate.

Comment: I mentioned in the comment above that a friend suggested replacing the inductor with a 1mH one. Is there a way in which I can determine if the inductor will become saturated? I think I mentioned before that the system only uses about 30-40mA

Comment: The inductor saturation current should be higher than the chip's switch current limit.

Comment: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_ZILLTEK-ZTP7193MA_C481284.html

Answer (score 3):

The question is whether this is just normal switching activity of the IC, or whether the circuit is unstable and maybe oscillating in an unexpected way. I've had experience of a TI part which had a great tendency to oscillate at 200 MHz; at first glance, it just looked like the output was a bit more noisy than expected.

What can really help is to get hold of the manufacturer's evaluation board for the IC; a quick load-test can then establish what the noise level should be, and you can see the components & PCB layout they have used to minimise it

Comment: That would be one of the next things to do. I don't doubt the chip is not the best (there's a reason why it was the only one in stock I guess), just trying to see if I can't make it right with a few external component changes only

Comment: For what it is worth, we generally found the Linear Tech devices (such as the LT8609) much easier to use than the TI parts; we had major space constraints, so the PCB design was sub-optimal, and the LT parts seemed to be more tolerant of that. Unfortunately they are also more expensive, but maybe that isn't a coincidence.